# Alternatives to Ring Stands

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm trying to find an alternative to simple ring stands to hold a simple electrochemical cell.

The issue is that it is difficult to adjust the height to the right position to within even a couple inches. If you try to screw the stand in it can drop or lean, and I need to be able to adjust it to within at least an inch without it falling down.

I use a micrometer to adjust an electrode coming in from the top, and I don't have a lot of play to push down.

It is also not easy to adjust the stand from under a few hood, due to the nature of the screw.

It would also be nice if the clamp could be adjusted along the y-axis to move it closer or farther from the stand for different situations.

[image: Current Ring Stand Situation]

Comment: Let me guess: You used the "breaking-bad" tag because it's bad when the precious glassware breaks? :D

Comment: Surprisingly we've never broken glassware using this method. It's extremely bad when you go through the trouble to set everything up and then you mess up the junction by adjusting the stand just a little bit too high, before even starting the experiment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about puting the whole stand on the lab-lift, hopefully there will be also some precision version.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a really good idea! Are there ones made with about 6in, 15cm or so in the z-axis? I'm finding ones with like 3mm z-axis movement. It doesn't have to be too precise as the micrometer on the top has a few cm of play.

Comment: After looking through some catalogs, I found some and I think this will be the simplest method. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could offer you some of the organic chemistry tricks ;) As for the y-axis movement, use those: 
http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/labware/labware-products.html?TablePage=102186322 and
http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/z243620

Answer (score 2):

On the more improvised/DIY side, you may be able to get away with something like a gooseneck clamp of the sort commonly used for microphones; something like this:

[image]

(from [here](https://www.walimex.biz/walimex-pro-Studio-Clamp-MX-with-Gooseneck))

Obviously they're not really designed to be exposed to hazardous chemicals, though, and you'll want to make sure that it can handle the weight you need to put on it without bending further.

Comment: This seems pretty interesting, I'll go ahead and order one and see how it works out. I'll probably try having the stand pre-adjusted then just clip/unclip it from a mount to get it ready. I'm hoping others will have more answers as well, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does your university have a workshop with some precision mechanics, who can handle a milling machine and a lathe to process metals and teflon?

Talk to the guys and explain them what you need. If they know their job (and I'm certain they do) they'll figure out all technical details and build it.

Comment: Our machine shop doesn't really _do_ that much, and is understaffed, so that would probably take a year and we still wouldn't get it. I was hoping there was just something available to buy off the shelf maybe with some grooves in the stand instead of just being flat

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about lab suppliers in the US. For CV and SWV only used electrochemical cells from Metrohm (as far as I remember) where the lid was fixed to a stand and the glass cell body scewed to it. The position of the working electrode was adjusted via a teflon screw (with a drill-hole along the longer axis).

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a much better setup, and not too hard to machine together, it's a shame our university lacks the ability to do something like that. I'll definitely keep that in mind when thinking about a better way to proceed.